# Get Windows 8 geolocation info from not Windows Store app

Tags: windows, windows-8, geolocation, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to get Windows 8 geolocation info not from Windows Store App? I mean, maybe there is way to get geolocation from command line app, or from noе .NET languages.

Comment: Google "winrt api from desktop application" and you'll get more than enough answers.

Comment: I found answer in Intel's blog https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications